# Вывести разных роутах разные рендеринги в koa

Tags: node.js, koa.js

Не могу получить как в expresse данный вывод

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index');
});
```

Только такой же эффект но в koa. Я использовал модуль [koa-views](https://github.com/queckezz/koa-views)

Но не смог вывести их в разных роутах, пробовал так

```
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {extension: 'pug'}));    
app.use(router.get('/', async (ctx) => {
        await ctx.render('index');
    })
);
```

В этом случае ошибка выводит TypeError: middleware must be a function!
Если делать так

```
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {extension: 'pug'}));
router.get('/', (ctx) => {
    app.use(async (res) => {
        await res.render('index');
    });
});
```

И я уже запутался, как вообще вывести рендер для разных роутов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const Koa = require('koa'),
Router = require('koa-router'),
logger = require('koa-logger'),
views = require('koa-views'),
serve = require('koa-static-server'),
app = new Koa(),
router = new Router();
app.use(logger());
app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', {extension: 'pug'}));

routers('/', 'login', {title: 'Авторизация'});
routers('/registration', 'registration', {title: 'Регистрация'});

function routers(path, page, object) {
    router.get(path, async (ctx) => {
       await ctx.render(page, object);
    })
}

app.use(router.routes());

module.exports = app;
```